# How do I get the original finder view back?

Tags: finder, macos

For some strange reason, Finder has changed to a different layout and I can't figure out how to revert it to the standard one.

This is what it looks like now:

[image: New strange Finder layout]

How do I revert it to the original, default layout, that has folders, drives and devices in the left-most column and all the other files and folders in the middle panes?

I see the original layout when I go to upload a file here, so you can see the screenshot here:

[image: Original Layout]

How do I get back that original layout and prevent it from changing again? This is the second or third time it has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Show the Toolbar with ⌥⌘T or View → Show Toolbar
- Show the Sidebar with ⌥⌘S or View → Show Sidebar